# How to get image from HBITMAP type with ctypes?

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I try to use `ctypes` get a image from the dll, but the dll api just return a integer number(like this: 1795493677).
I want get the image(PIL or other style),Can someone know how to do?

**The dll api**
`HBITMAP lmc1_GetPrevBitmap2(int nBMPWIDTH,int nBMPHEIGHT);`

**The code**

```py
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

dllPath = ""
dll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary(dllPath)
dll.lmc1_GetPrevBitmap2.restype = wintypes.HBITMAP
img = dll.lmc1_GetPrevBitmap2(400, 400) # img is a integer number
```

Comment: `HBITMAP` is a *handle*.  It is only supposed to be an opaque number.  You'll need a different API to get the actual image, but with no information about the DLL being used can't say more.  If the handle is 64-bit you'll need to set the `.restype` of the function correctly, however, such as `dll.lmc1_getPrevBitmap2.restype = ctypes.c_void_p` if the handle is a `void*`.

Comment: I don't know how to do now, can you give me some api or solutions?

Comment: I don't know what DLL you are using or what API set is available.

Comment: the dll is 32bit, and I set  `restype = wintypes.HBITMAP`

Comment: the dll is other company give me, just one dll, the dll can't return python image,all api just  return HBITIMAGE.

Comment: `HBITIMAGE` isn't a Microsoft type.  So no idea.

Comment: The C# have library that can get the image from the HBITMAP, but the python I don't know.